# Enough for arima ACF without PACF

Tags: arima, acf-pacf

I try to create it myself in ARIMA code.
I managed to create ACF.
With PACF everything is much more complicated(working with matrices).
Can I do without PACF using ACF?
Or maybe who knows an easier way to get PACF?

I assume you'll ask why not use "ARIMA"from " R".
The thing is, I want to use it in another program.
I tried to connect scripts from "R", but it works very slowly and not always correctly.

Comment: Why do you want to use the (P)ACF? If it's to fit an ARIMA model, then the more modern approach is to search through models to minimize AIC, AICc or BIC. This is also implemented in `auto.arima()`, and if you fit a model, anyway, then calculating these information criteria should not be hard.

Comment: So far to " AIC " and " BIC " has not gone) I confess that "ARIMA" know little, not to mention " auto.arima". 
If I understand correctly, it is possible to do without "ACF", "PACF" using "AIC", "BIC"?

Everywhere where I read about the "ARIMA", the first thing was a test of stationarity.
"ACF" shows well whether there is a trend or data like noise.